# error installing RandForestGUI (hence 'rgl', 'X11) in "R version 2.13.1 (2011-07-08)"

Tags: r, x11, rgl

I have installed "R version 2.13.1 (2011-07-08)", over "Ubuntu 10.04 - Lucid Lynx".
(I use RStudio 0.94.92), with all the headers needed to compile the many different packages I already installed.
I got stuck with   :  **install.packages("RandForestGUI")**. Everything ran smoothly until

```
.....
* DONE (sciplot)
ERROR: dependency ‘rgl’ is not available for package ‘clusterSim’
* removing ‘/home/rs/R/i486-pc-linux-gnu-library/2.13/clusterSim’
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package 'clusterSim' had non-zero exit status
ERROR: dependency ‘clusterSim’ is not available for package ‘RandForestGUI’
* removing ‘/home/rs/R/i486-pc-linux-gnu-library/2.13/RandForestGUI’
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package 'RandForestGUI' had non-zero exit status
```

I tried to   : **install.packages("rgl")**    but

```
Installing package(s) into ‘/home/rs/R/i486-pc-linux-gnu-library/2.13’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
provo con l'URL 'http://rm.mirror.garr.it/mirrors/CRAN/src/contrib/rgl_0.92.798.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 1677772 bytes (1.6 Mb)
URL aperto
==================================================
downloaded 1.6 Mb

* installing *source* package ‘rgl’ ...
checking for gcc... gcc
checking for C compiler default output file name... a.out
checking whether the C compiler works... yes
checking whether we are cross compiling... no
….
checking for libpng-config... yes
configure: using libpng-config
configure: using libpng dynamic linkage
checking for X... no
configure: error: X11 not found but required, configure aborted.
ERROR: configuration failed for package ‘rgl’
* removing ‘/home/rs/R/i486-pc-linux-gnu-library/2.13/rgl’
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package 'rgl' had non-zero exit status
```

Finally I tried    : **install.packages("X11")** and

```
Installing package(s) into ‘/home/rs/R/i486-pc-linux-gnu-library/2.13’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
Warning in install.packages :
  package ‘X11’ is not available (for R version 2.13.1)
```

... was stuck!.

Is it possible to have **RandForestGUI**  in "R version 2.13.1 (2011-07-08)"?
Many thanks, Roberto Scotti

Answer (score 5):

Couple of rerequisites:

- Use an R binary from [the CRAN Ubuntu repository](http://cran.r-project.org/bin/linux/ubuntu/).
- Do `sudo apt-get install r-base-dev` to complement your R environment for local package installation if you haven't already done so.
- Then do  `sudo apt-get install r-cran-rgl` as that is the *hardest* one to OpenGL headers.

Now try again with the `RForestGUI` package and its other dependants, and analyse the errors package by package.

Answer (score 2):

The error indicates that you don't have the relevant X11 headers package for your OS. This is **not** an R package. You need to install that using whatever tools Ubuntu provides (as it is a Debian off-shoot, `apt get` should work, but there may be other, preferred techniques for adding packages to your OS.

The R Installation and Administration manual suggests that, for Debian, the relevant OS package needed is `xorg-dev`. Try installing that using your package manager in Ubuntu, and retry to install **rgl** inside R.

@Dirk Eddelbuettel will no doubt comment that there are pre-built packages in Ubuntu for many of R's packages or at least a meta-package for R Development that will make sure you have all the header packages for your OS available so you can build R packages at install time. I don't use Ubuntu or Debian so I cannot help with this aspect of your Q.

Comment: @Dirk Eddelbuettel Would you please provide a link to a discussion of a meta-package for Ubuntu?

Comment: @Lao Tzu Is this what you want? http://cran.r-project.org/bin/linux/ubuntu/ There was a typo in the link Dirk gave in his Answer. I have updated it.

Comment: @Gavin Simpson Thanks, but I've looked at that before. I'm trying to figure out how to install packages from R-Forge, or from any random `.tar.gz` source file on the internet. When I do `install.packages("RBloomberg", repos="http://R-Forge.r-project.org")` or so, I get errors. Ditto if I copy to disk and set `repos="/home/laotzu/R/packagename/whereiputthetarball"`.

Answer (score 0):

Had a similar problem for the clusterSim package in OS X.

Found the solution on the [rstudio board](https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/200819288-rgl-unable-to-open-X11-):

X11 isn't installed by default on newer versions of OS X, so I had to install [Quartz](https://www.xquartz.org/) (the osx distribution of X11)